# I want to change the color of ggplot bar charts

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I want to change the color of ggplot bar charts manually using the scale_color_manual function.  Here is the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(UM.Leads, aes(Leads, Count, fill = Model)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  xlab("Electrode Model") + 
  ylab("DBS Leads") + 
  ggtitle("University of Minnesota") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("darkgoldenrod1", "grey55", "dodgerblue1")) + 
  theme_classic()
```

I cannot seem to change the fill of the bar graphs from the default pink, green, and blue that ggplot provides.  Any help would be much appreciated!

See plot here:  http://rpubs.com/Gopher16/393415

Comment: You have mapped your data to `fill`, but set a scale for `color`. Try `scale_fill_manual(...)`

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate the comment from @Jack Brookes and create a reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(
  gp = factor(rep(letters[1:3], each = 10)),
  y = rnorm(30)
)
ggplot(df, aes(gp, y, fill=gp)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkgoldenrod1", "grey55", "dodgerblue1")) + 
  theme_classic()
```